# Upload process don't save the right name in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a code in php with validation ok all working properly but my problem is that when I try to save in database I obtain something like this:

```
img_id   img_small           img_big           
  5      /tmp/phpdlYkiG      /tmp/phph3dhka
```

I don't know why php save that name because the images have a diffent names like koala.jpg and horse.jpg

Here is my code in order to see if somebody have any suggestion...

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_type_1.php" method="POST" >        
  <input type="file" name="img_small_1" id="img_small_1">
  <input type="file" name="img_big_1" id="img_big_1">

  <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">                                   
</form>
```

and this is my php code:

```
if ( (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_small_1"]["tmp_name"], $target)) && (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_big_1"]["tmp_name"], $target2)) ){
    $img_title_1 = $_POST['img_title_1'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO press (img_title, img_small, img_big) VALUES ('$img_title_1', '$img_small_1', '$img_big_1')";

    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

    if(!$retval) {
      die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($conn);

    echo "Your files has been uploaded";        

} else {

    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your files."; 

    exit;
}
```

This code work properly the only problem is that save into database that strange names and I need to use that names...

Thanks! - Waiting for help!

Comment: You don't show how you set `$img_small_1` && `$img_big_1`. My guess is you are using `$_FILES["img_small_1"]["tmp_name"]` && `$_FILES["img_big_1"]["tmp_name"]` instead of `$_FILES["img_small_1"]["name"]` && `$_FILES["img_big_1"]["name"]`

Comment: If I remove the "tmp_name" and put only "name" I receive the result of this echo:   "Sorry, there was an error uploading your files.";

Comment: don't change/remove `["tmp_name"]` from your file moves - `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_small_1"]["tmp_name"])` ONLY from your var declarations - `$img_small_1 = $_FILES["img_small_1"]["name"]` && `$img_big_1 = $_FILES["img_big_1"]["name"]`

Comment: Problem Resolved! Thanks my friend you have reason I need to first save into variable like this:       $img_small_1 = $_FILES["img_small_1"]["name"];     
  $img_big_1   = $_FILES["img_big_1"]["name"];      and now mysql is receiving the real names... Thousand of thanks! GREAT!

Comment: glad to help. added it as an answer.

Comment: Sean I can't find where I can close as resolved this question please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is probably not in the code that you are showing but in the code you are not showing, which is your variable declarations for `$img_small_1` && `$img_big_1`. Taking a guess you have

```
$img_small_1 = $_FILES["img_small_1"]["tmp_name"];
$img_big_1 = $_FILES["img_big_1"]["tmp_name"];
```

but you want/need

```
$img_small_1 = $_FILES["img_small_1"]["name"];
$img_big_1 = $_FILES["img_big_1"]["name"];
```

Comment: Thanks is already resolve as I mention above! but thanks for your help brother...

Comment: i was the commenter from above that gave you the answer. this answer is so you can close your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
$img_title_1 = $_POST['img_title_1'];
```

**Should be:**

```
$img_title_1 = $_FILES["img_small_1"]["name"]
```

Comment: `["tmp_name"]` is part of `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`. `$_POST['img_title_1']` is probably a input text field that the OP did not add to his sample form code.

Comment: Exactly @Sean you are right, Answer edited `$img_title_1` is a actual file name in my case.

Comment: "img_title_1" is the name of a simple text field, but I don't mention that because that work well, the only problem is with the images names that with some reason MySQL is not receiving the real names

Comment: @abelvf please let me know where you are getting value of `$img_small_1` in your code and how?  I suggest `$img_small_1 = $_FILES["img_small_1"]["name"]`

Answer (score 0):

A Simple Example of File Uploading

```
$uploadDir = "Your_upload_dir";
$img_small = $_FILES['img_small_1'];

$img_small_name = $img_small['name']; // get image name
$img_small_tmpName = $img_small['tmp_name'];
$img_small_fileSize = $img_small['size'];
$img_small_fileType = $img_small['type'];

if ($img_small['error'] == 0)
{
    $img_small_filePath = $uploadDir . $img_small_name;
    $result = move_uploaded_file($img_small_tmpName,  img_small_filePath); //return true or false

}
```